# How to throw exception for statment?

Tags: java, exception

HI !
I want to throw exception for the line

```
BarcodeNo=Long.parseLong(jTextField1.getText())
```

I done this in a way

```
BarcodeNo=Long.parseLong(jTextField1.getText()) throw new NumberFormatException("Enter Numbers Only ");
```

But this way compiler throws error stating ";" required

So anyone can tell me how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect that you want to do something particular from the exception thrown at this particular line. Right ? And I also suspect that the reason behind is important to give you an accurate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That *will* already thrown an exception if the text isn't in the right format. If you want to change the exception *message*, you'd have to catch the exception and throw a new one:

```
try {
  BarcodeNo = Long.parseLong(jTextField1.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  throw new NumberFormatException("Enter Numbers Only");
}
```

I wouldn't suggest that you try to use exception message as user-visible messages though - they're more reasonable for logging than for showing an end user.

Comment: God when I just ask for details, you already guessed what he had in mind !

Answer (score -1):

yes you should put

```
try
{
BarcodeNo=Long.parseLong(jTextField1.getText());
}
catch(Exception e)
{
throw new NumberFormatException("Enter Numbers Only ");

}
```

Comment: I would try to avoid catching just "Exception" for something like this. The exception which will be thrown when the string isn't a number is well documented. Catching `Exception` will mask errors such as `jTextField1` itself being null.

Comment: -1, I disagree with encouraging catching a general `Exception` for almost anything, unless you're writing container code or something similar.

Comment: @Ankur - I understand. However, catching a more specific exception would also allow the code to compile. When it comes to catching `Exception`s, I'm usually not very forgiving, because I've waded through tons of legacy code that does it. Along with obscuring bugs and making code less maintainable, it's just a nuisance to deal with.

Comment: @Ankur - Sure. Thanks for understanding. I hope I didn't come off too abrasive here; I'm simply trying to rid the world of unnecessary `catch(Exception e)`s, one catch at a time. :)